# Find common approximate subtring with weight and penalty

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given two random substrings (not necessarily same length) with only English letters, find the best common approximate substrings using dynamic programming.

Each letter has a weight `w` of given value (i.e. set A with weight 1, B with 2, or all letters to 1), and penalty `p` of a random value.

The best "common approximate substring" is defined as finding the best contiguous substring with highest sum of `w` for each letter, and minus the penalty `p` when there is a mismatch.

For example, given two strings `"AABCC"` and `"AADCC"` with mismatch penalty `p=3`. When `w` for "A" is 1 and "C" is 2, then the output would be `"CC"` because it has the highest weight `2 + 2 = 4`, which outweighs all other substrings. If `w` for each letter is 1, then the output would be just `"AA"`. etc.

Right now I can understand the dynamic approach for finding the longest common substrings https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-longest-common-substring/, but I need help coming up with a dynamic programing algorithm for best approximate common substrings in C++. I feel like this problem is just to find the LCS with weight and penalty.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Let's create a class for weights. I don't want to set weights for all letters cause I set `default_weight`:

```
class LetterWeights
{
    std::map<char, double> weights;
    const double default_weight;
    const double penalty;
public:
    LetterWeights(const double& def_weight, const double& pen)
        : default_weight(def_weight)
        , penalty(pen)
    {};
    void Set(const char& letter, const double& weight) { weights[letter] = weight; }
    const double Get(const char& letter)
    {
        if (weights.find(letter) != weights.end())
        {
            return weights[letter] - penalty;
        }
        else
        {
            return default_weight - penalty;
        }
    }
};
```

I think we need own class for substring where we will have start index of sting and length of substring:

```
static const int kEmptyIndex = -2;
struct Substring
{
    int start = kEmptyIndex, len = 0;
    double weight = 0;
    const bool Empty() const {return start == kEmptyIndex; }
    void Clear() 
    {
        start = kEmptyIndex; 
        len = 0;
        weight = 0;
    }
    std::string GetString(const std::string& s)
    {
        return s.substr(start, len);
    }
};
```

Now Let's write LRC. Algorithm:
Input: string1 (size = N), string2 (size = M).
Result: pair of substring and its weight.
Imagine that we have a table X(N x M) where X(i, j) is equal to 1 if string1[i] == string2[j] and 0 in other case. So all substrings is in diagonals of X: if X(0,1), x(1, 2) and X(1, 3) = 1 and other cells = 0 we can find max substring by length as string1[0:1] or string2[1:2] cause X(0,1) and X(1, 2) are lying in one diagonal. Sowe can fill the table by values and find max sequence of ones in diagonal.
We can fill the table and find max sequence in `O(M*N)` times.
But I don't want to create the table. We can find substrings without it, but we will find substrings 'by diagonals'. And we will use weight function instead of length (for finding maximum substring);
Let's create another helpful class:

```
struct MaxSubstring
{
    Substring max, curr;
    void CheckMax()
    {
        if (!curr.Empty() && (max.Empty() || curr.weight > max.weight))
            max = curr;
        curr.Clear();
    }
    void Add(const int index, const double& weight)
    {
        if (curr.Empty())
        {
            curr.start = index;
        }
        ++curr.len;
        curr.weight += weight;
    }
};
```

Here we have current and maximum substrings on diag. I need the class for copypaste clearing. Now we can write main class:

```
class LCS
{
    const std::string string1, string2;
public:
    LCS(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
        : string1(s1)
        , string2(s2)
    {};
    std::pair<std::string, double> FindMax(LetterWeights& weights)
    {
        MaxSubstring res;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < string1.size(); ++i)
        {
            res.curr = MaxDiagSum(weights, i, 0);
            res.CheckMax();
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < string2.size(); ++j)
        {
            res.curr = MaxDiagSum(weights, 0, j);
            res.CheckMax();
        }
        
        if (res.max.Empty())
        {
            return std::make_pair("", 0);
        }
        return std::make_pair(res.max.GetString(string1), res.max.weight);
    }
    Substring MaxDiagSum(LetterWeights& weights, const int i_start, const int j_start)
    {
        MaxSubstring res;
        int i1 = i_start, i2 = j_start;
        for ( ; i1 < string1.size() && i2 < string2.size(); ++i1, ++i2)
        {
            if (string1[i1] == string2[i2])
            {
                res.Add(i1, weights.Get(string1[i1]));
            }
            else 
            {
                res.CheckMax();
            }
        }
        res.CheckMax();
        return res.max;
    }
};
```

main function for example:

```
int main(void)
{
    
    std::string s1, s2;
    std::cin >> s1;
    std::cin >> s2;
    double penalty = 1.0;
    LetterWeights weight(1.0, penalty);
    
    weight.Set('a', 10.0);
    
    LCS lcs(s1, s2);
    auto res = lcs.FindMax(weight);
    std::cout << res.first << " --> " << res.second << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

times: `O(M*N)`; memory: `O(max(M, N))`.

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstand a little, the substring returned need to be 'contiguous', and the penalty value is the same for all letters. Only the weight is different for each letter.

Comment: When I test this with two strings "aadcc" and "aabcc", it returns "aacc", it skips the mismatched letter, which should not happen.

Comment: You're right, my code was not useful. But I rewrite it.